# Run shell script from C and want to get the value of an environment variable set by the shell script

Tags: c

From a C code, I execute a shell script:

`system("./script.sh")` and also tried `system("source ./script.sh")`

The shell script sets an environment variable called `STATUS`:

`export STATUS="success"`

I try to get the value of `STATUS` from the same C code after executing the shell script:

`char *status=getenv("STATUS")`

`getenv()` returns `NULL`, and couldn't find the environment variable.

I guess the problem is that the shell script runs in a new process, then the variable `STATUS` is set in that new process, so it is destroyed once the new process terminates.

Please help, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `I guess the problem is that the shell script runs in a new process, then the variable STATUS is set in that new process, so it destroyed once the new process terminates.` -- Bingo.

Comment: You need to find another way for the subprocess to communicate with the parent process.  You could write the data to a file, or use a pipe to communicate with the parent process, etc.

Comment: Please define the *real* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you want to persist a value from one process to the next, there are probably better ways than using environment variables.  Like writing to a file, maybe?

Comment: You could use something like `popen` and print the result for the parent to read.